# Synaptic Package Manager dependency is not satisfiable

Tags: wireless, synaptic

I am not familiar with linux but I am learning
I installed the latest Ubuntu 14 on my machine vostro 1000. 64 bits.

I do not have WIFI working and try to follow the topics 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

I need to have synaptic

I found this page and a link : 
http://linux.softpedia.com/get/System/Software-Distribution/Synaptic-2028.shtml

However if I want to install , I got this message :
"Dependency is not satisfiable : libetp.1.4.12"

What does it mean ? Can you help ?

Comment: run `sudo apt-get update` followed by  `sudo apt-get install -f` and  post the error.

Comment: Welcome to AU! g_p is right, but I would to ask you to [attach](https://askubuntu.com/posts/529638/edit) the error message(s) to your question instead of a comment for readability.

Comment: Ubuntu is installed another machine , I will try to do screenshot next time and store to my usb then download to the computer where I have the internet. Could you tell me where the folder synaptic should be ?

Comment: sorry, It's seem that I do not synaptic as per comment below and I have to use apt-get

Answer (score 0):

Actually -- that's `apt-get` for you instead of synaptic.

Few tricks for you to start rolling off on your own:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

This loads up all updates/upgrades that is up to current.

```
sudo apt-cache search KEYWORD
```

If I entered 'apache2' as keyword in that command line (`sudo apt-cache search apache2`), then it will list all of repository available for you to choose.  Once you found what you like, fire this command to have that package installed for you:

```
sudo apt-get install KEYWORD -y
```

You see, when using apt-get as package manager, it's doing you so much favor because it will compile and do all of dirty work in configuring and linking the system to new package.  I couldn't live without this.  :)

Answer (score 0):

True, you certainly don't actually need Synaptic to do that stuff with your BCM adapter.  In linux everything ends up in a terminal anyway so there's nothing you can do in synaptic you can't do with apt-get.  Synaptic is a front and for apt-get.

However you should still have synaptic IMO.  But in the future DO NOT use something like softpedia to install something like that.  I'd never use softpedia for anything.  It has a bad habit of adding attachments I'd consider malware.

Always look in the repos first, and don't use 3rd party ppa's until you know what you're doing a bit more, and I never use them unless there is no other way to do what I want to do.  Which is almost never.

Try in terminal:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install synaptic

Comment: synaptic could not be found